# IntelliJ IDEA - What is the keyboard shortcut for 'git pull' command?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Since Intellij relies on keyboard shortcuts a lot,I was wondering if there is one for "git pull" command. That would save couple of seconds.
I am using Intellij Version 15.0.4 on Windows.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set one yourself: Go to the IntelliJ settings, open the tab "Keymap" and search for "git pull" in the top right. Just set one of the found matches, it will change the others too.

Comment: Use Ctrl+T, it's a default shortcut of command Update that's pulling changes from Git.

Answer (score 34):

What you are looking for, is `VCS->Update Project`

The default windows keybinding is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> 
. (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for mac)

If this keyboard combination does not work, just expand `VCS` in the main window, then find the key combo in the `Update Project` option